# Is there a benchmark for real time communication(websocket or ajax polling etc)?

Tags: sockets, websocket, real-time

So I figure the definition of real time updates/communication is when updates made by one user are relayed to other users subscribed to the object as soon as they are made.

but this is not instantaneous(data takes finite time to travel). So I suppose that means a very short time.

If you use ajax polling every 5 seconds, the time taken for the user A to see something user B did is: 5+t1+t2 (time taken for data(http reques) to come from user B's PC to the server. t2 is time taken for data to come from server to User A's PC).

t1+t2 is the minimum delay that cannot be taken out of the picture(sure sockets reduce this time, but those factors are still present, however small). 
So you can have delay of t1+t2+d in case of sockets. d is the time taken for server to notice event happened internally and propogate it(depends on CPU power)
My question is: is there any established benchmark/standard that defines how small d should be for the communication to be realtime.

Or is realtime just a general term we throw around daily?
This is out of sheer curiosity rather than any application. I am just curious if there are any established standards for realtime data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "is there any established benchmark/standard that defines how small d
>   should be for the communication to be realtime?"

Your question is a valid one. An application is always defined by a characteristic latency time `t`. In different contexts, "realtime" can have an entirely different meaning with respect to `t`.

I would say the accepted "standard" for defining realtime event processing in the context of applications involving the web and human users is that (multiple) users should be able to interact with the application without "feeling" an impeding delay. The application must "feel responsive". In numbers this could mean that the overall latency time between request and response (general terms) should be not higher than on the order of ~100 ms. The human response time to real world events is on this order of magnitude. Online games requiring extremely fast reaction times are absolutely playable with an overall latency (round-trip) time somwhere between 10 and 60 ms.

In other contexts, such as in a lab or for controlling machines in industry, realtime event processing sometimes means **guaranteed** event processing within milliseconds, microseconds or even faster. This is an entirely different situation.

Coming back to web applications, I think modern realtime web services display one or multiple of the following characteristics:

- the user interface is extremely responsive, partly realized by local execution in e.g. JavaScript. Eventual communication between code running on user side (in e.g. the browser) and the remote web application is executed asynchronously (hidden from the user).
- the back-end implementation is based on efficient event processing techniques rather than periodic polls.
- a persistent TCP/IP connection is used between user(s) and back-end in order to get rid of latencies and overhead due to connection opening/closing (this is where e.g. WebSockets come into play)

I hope this answers your question in general terms. If you want to know something more specifically, feel free to write a comment.

Comment: I was just wondering if there is any International Standard defining realtime in web communications. Realtime right now is used for extremely fast communication. That's a like saying a car is very heavy. very heavy is not an enumerable entity i.e cannot be measured or compare. Saying that a car weighs 1000Kg makes sense. It is 1000 times heavier than the block of metal stored in PAris that defines 1 KG. Very responsive or very fast aren't enumerable either.

Comment: I think you agree that in the real world fault-tolerant and self-correcting network protocols used over long distances have mean latencies that vary among different endpoints. Also you have to agree that a "realtime" classification depends on the application, as outlined above. Therefore, it does not make sense to define a standard. It makes sense, however, to classify an application by the order of magnitude `t` (as introduced above) needs to be of in order to meet the requirements.

Comment: I think that would be a fair standard. t1+t2 depend on protocol used and distance/network. We can probably conduct timing tests to determine this. d should be as small as possible: say 100 ms for web applications. even t1 and t2 have breakups. You can break it up into hops time and protocol time. Perhaps we can also define protocols to be suitable for realtime application if the protocol speed is less than 10 ms(in addition data transfer time). and so on. just thinking

Comment: It is entirely unclear to me what you are thinking there. No need to break something up. If an application **requires** a maximum *total* delay of about 100 ms between request and response (or input and output, if you wish to say so) in order to be applied in *real time*, then this has to be realized. It does not matter where the 100 ms go. As I said, the expression *realtime* entirely depends on the application and can mean any characteristic latency.